# Ajax request has encountered an error just on either safari or firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, safari

when i try to click the share button i get Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) in the console and alert says Ajax request has encountered an error knowing that this doesn't happened on staging just on production and on safari or firefox.
I spent hours trying to figure it out

here is my code

```
    $(document).on("click",".btn-share-generate-js",function(e) {
  var url = $(this).data("share-url");
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  var message = $("input:radio.vt:checked").val();
  var clickedBtn = $(this);

  clickedBtn.find(".icon-link").addClass('hide');
  clickedBtn.find(".icon-arrows-cw").removeClass('hide');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'share[message]': message
    },

    success: function(data) {
      clickedBtn.find(".icon-link").removeClass('hide');
      clickedBtn.find(".icon-arrows-cw").addClass('hide');
      if (data.error == true) {
        alert(data.error_message);
      } else {
        replaceShareButtonWith(data.share_url);
      }
    },
    error: function(){
      clickedBtn.find(".icon-link").removeClass('hide');
      clickedBtn.find(".icon-arrows-cw").addClass('hide');
      alert("Ajax request has encountered an error.")
    },
    });
  return false;
});

$(document).on("click",".social-media-reshare-btn",function(e) {
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  window.open(url, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=245,width=550');
  return false;
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your server responds with a `500` error, the only reason is that you are sending a slightly different request causing the server-side misbehave. You should open the developer console (of Safari and/or Firefox), switch to the `Network` tab, and retry the action. Now you can inspect the entire outgoing request to see how it is different from the browsers that work fine.

Once you have the root cause of the problem, you can decide either

- the client is sending something wrong: so now you determine how to fix the above code
- the server should not fail given this slightly different incoming request: so you should fix the server code

Comment: The difference in the Response Headers which the connection is keep alive and the content-type is text/plain: charset=utf-8 which the working request method is for content-type has the value of application/json: charset=utf-8 
do yo think here where the problem kicks in

Comment: That could make a huge difference. Some servers do read the incoming `Content-Type` and go to different code path. So now you need to figure out why in the production environment the ` dataType: 'json'` jQuery parameter does not give you `Content-Type: application/json; ...`. Is the jQuery version different? Are the URLs not in the same origin or CORS headers not setup correctly?